# How to calculate formally the running time of the naive polynomial evaluation at a point

Tags: time-complexity, polynomials

I understand intuitively why the time complexity of the naive polynomial evaluation at a point is ϴ(n^2). However, I'm not sure how to calculate formally the running time in order to show it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite `ϴ(n^2)`, but `ϴ(mn)`, where `m` and `n` are the number of terms in each polynomial.

[image]

There are trivially `m * n` multiplication required, equal to the number of ways to pair coefficients `a_i * b_j` between the two polynomials.

There are also additions to consider; however, since any certain pair of coefficients `a_i, b_j` only belongs to **one** power of `x`, it will only be added **once** to a coefficient in the final polynomial. Therefore there can only be up to `O(mn)` additions.

Therefore the overall time complexity of naive multiplication is `ϴ(mn)`.